# automating RAPIDSHARE piracy file take down process

Tags: mozilla, piracy, piracy-prevention, ubiquity

I found a new search engine that speeds up finding piracy files from rapidshare, how could I automate a tool that finds our product using this engine and outputs the list of the rapidshare URLs that will be then sent to abuse@rapidshare.com.

search engine:

http://rapidlibrary.com/
(note, the captcha image appears just once there)

Below is a nice script that could perhaps do this pretty easily?

http://www.nasser.me/ubiquity/rapidsharecom-link-checker/

Comment: And don't forget bittorrent.  And usenet.  And edonkey, jdownloader, rar-files-in-jpegs, and don't copy that floppy.

Answer (score 2):

I thought about this in the past and being a "tv show pirate" myself it kinda annoys me why free torrent sites like The Pirate Bay and Mininova are being taken down while other not so free sites like Rapidshare, Megaupload and so on **host the files** and continue to **make millions** out of piracy.

The marketing model of those sites is viral, meaning the more a user spreads his link the more points he will receive and the less he will have to pay for his "subscription" in the future so is just obvious to suppose that those same links would be well spread over the Internet.

I would just search and scrap all the major warez forums out there, for a week or two and after that a search on the web should find all the remaining blogs / sites that still point to the pirated file.